# Function that converts from double to string has issues with the fractional part

Tags: c++, string, double, data-conversion

I have to create a computer that can calculate any expression that's inputted. I reached a point where I have the result of one expression and I have to convert it from double into string in order to insert it back into the string that's been inputted and continue the process with the other expressions. I am not allowed to use STL functions or external libraries, so I've been trying to make a function myself. But I have issues with converting the fractional part of the result.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

string conversieDoubleInString(double nr)
{
    string s = "";
    if (nr < 0) {
        s += '-';
        nr = -1 * nr;
    }

    int parte_intreaga = nr;
    float parte_fr = floor((nr - parte_intreaga) * pow(10, 5));
    int parte_fractionara = parte_fr;
    parte_fractionara -= 1;
    if (parte_fractionara != 0)
        while (parte_fractionara % 10 == 0)
            parte_fractionara = parte_fractionara / 10;

    int numar_cifre_fractionale_inreg = 0;
    double copie = parte_fractionara;
    while (copie > 1) {
        numar_cifre_fractionale_inreg++;
        copie = copie / 10;
    }
    while (parte_intreaga != 0) {
        int n = parte_intreaga % 10;
        parte_intreaga = parte_intreaga / 10;
        s = char('0' + n) + s;
    }
    if (parte_fractionara != 0) {
        s += '.';
        while (parte_fractionara > 1) {

            s += char('0' + (int)parte_fractionara % 10);
            parte_fractionara = parte_fractionara / 10;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "1.1= " << conversieDoubleInString(1.1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "1.2= " << conversieDoubleInString(1.2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "1.3= " << conversieDoubleInString(1.3) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the stout is:

1.1= 1.9999
1.2= 1.8999
1.3= 1.99992

Comment: Your question would be better if you #1 Created a [mcve] containing an int main() that demonstrates just this function and has no user input - use fixed values. and #2 if you showed the actual and expected output for your code. Remember the main purpose of your question is to help readers perhaps years from now solve the same problem. At the current state we don't know what the problem is. I assume it returns a wrong result but maybe it crashes or something else happens.

Comment: I attempted to create a [mcve] here: [https://ideone.com/hLGcUM](https://ideone.com/hLGcUM)

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf).  You probably want to handle **nan**, **inf**, and **-inf**.

Comment: @drescherjm – Offsite links have a way of going stale over time. Best practice is to include all of your code directly in your question. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77580524/edit) your question to do that.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering so quickly! Sorry, I haven't used stackoverflow before so I'm clumsy when it comes to formatting the text and so on. I'll update the code immediately once I manage to convince the text editor that I properly indented the code.

Comment: Try fenced code blocks. Type ``` press enter paste code as it is press enter type ``` again and press enter

Comment: Ok, I think I managed to update it properly. I'll take a look at modf like Eljay suggested then I'll come back.

Comment: From what I tried and checked, the modf function wouldn't help much since it separates the fractional part but it's still stored as a double so when I multiply it with powers of 10 to move the fractional part into the integral part, depending on the numbers it still causes the issues with the floating point. In the end I used the to_string function to convert it as a whole into string even though I'm meant to create this function, but if there are other suggestions I'll try them out!

Comment: It would probably be useful to write a function to convert `int` to `std::string`, with a signature similar to this: `std::string convert_int_to_string(int i);` Then you could call that function twice, once to convert `parte_intreaga`, and a second time to convert `parte_fractionara`.